# How do I file a bug for kubuntu.org website?

Tags: kubuntu, bug-reporting, ubuntu-website

I have found an issue with the kubuntu.org website, the website that presents Kubuntu. Does the Kubuntu team accept bug reports for the website? How can I send feedback about the website itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the page (kubuntu.org) there is a [Contact Us](https://kubuntu.org/contact-us/) link, and on that page, there's a link to submit feedback on the site.  Specifically for *"if you have found an error on this website"*.  It's in plain sight ;)

FYI: It's fairly ubiquitous for websites to have a Contact link at the header or footer.